# git: pulling a certain branch from private git server repo and pushing it to BitBucket repo

Tags: git, svn, github, version-control, bitbucket

I am involved in a project working with a team of developers located in another country.

They have their own .git server. They only granted me read access (I can pull, but no push).

I have a Bitbucket account where I pushed the code as well. I added this as a `[remote “myBBaccount”]` in `.git/config` file.

If I want to make a change, I push my changes to Bitbucket and send them a pull request. They will then pull from my Bitbucket account. They want to use this setup as it is safer for them apparently.

I usually do a `git pull`, do my work (usually on master branch, I know, not the best idea) and then do a `git push myBBaccount`.

But recently, they asked me to pull `develop` branch instead of master. They have multiple branches on their repo. I am not sure how to deal with this new workflow.

Should I just do a `git branch –a` to see all the branches on my machine, and then `git checkout develop`, work on that and just push using `git push myBBaccount` ? I am not sure this is the way to go. Should I do any merges?

I am using git 2.0.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use recent enough version of git (>1.9 should do), `git checkout develop` should indeed create a new local branch named `develop` tracking the remote branch (i.e. `origin/develop`), and then you would push as you said (again, check your version of git - old versions did some surprising things when pushing).

As for merging, it depends on what the team wants from you.  If they just want you to make some changes on `develop` and submit them, you don't do any merging.

Comment: if `git branch -a` shows a list of branches (including develop), doesn't that mean `develop` is already been created on my local (by a regular pull) ? You mentioned `git checkout develop` would create a new local branch.

Comment: The simplest way to check whether a local `develop` branch already exists is to use `git branch` without `-a`: this will list all local ("regular") branches, and it won't list remote-tracking branches.

Comment: `git branch` was showing just the master branch. I then did `git branch -a` which revealed lots of branches (including develop). I then did a `git checkout develop` which indeed seems to have done something as now I can see develop even with `git branch` without -a. But I thought only `git branch -b` would create new branch

Comment: What you were seeing in `git branch -a` output was not local branch `develop`, but remote-tracking branch `origin/develop`.  That's not the same.  I recommend that you read an explanation on git branches, for example from [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches) book.

Comment: Thanks Janek, but other than that, seems that you agree with my setup. I'll mark your answer as the solution. I tested it and everything seems to work. Bitbucket is also showing me two branches now, master and develop.